# Implement multi class classification using SVM in R

Tags: r, svm

I am trying to implement Multi class classification using SVM  under e1071 package in R language. I read in a similar thread that SVM handles one vs one classifier by itself in the back end. Is it true.

Also, if I want to execute  One vs Rest classifier, how to do it. And, while printing the summary of SVM model, it doesnt show anywhere that it used One vs One classifier. How to confirm that.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer to my query above. I implemented one vs rest classifier by building binary classifiers on iris data present by default in R. It has 3 classes. So, I built 3 binary classifiers. Below is the code:

```
data(iris)
head(iris)
table(iris$Species)
nrow(iris)
index_iris<-sample.split(iris$Species,SplitRatio=.7)
trainset_iris<-iris[index_iris==TRUE,]
testset_iris<-iris[index_iris==FALSE,]
train_setosa<-trainset_iris
train_setosa$Species<-as.character(train_setosa$Species)
train_setosa$Species[train_setosa$Species!="setosa"]<-'0'
train_setosa$Species[train_setosa$Species=="setosa"]<-'1'
train_setosa$Species<-as.integer(train_setosa$Species)
tune_setosa<-tune.svm(Species~.,data=train_setosa,gamma=10^(-6:-1),cost=10^(-1:1))
summary(tune_setosa)
model_setosa<-svm(Species~.,data=train_setosa,kernel="radial",gamma=.1,cost=10,scale=TRUE,probabilities=TRUE,na.action=na.omit)
summary(model_setosa)
predict_setosa<-predict(model_setosa,testset_iris[,-5])
tab_setosa<-table(predict_setosa,testset_iris[,5])
tab_setosa

train_versicolor<-trainset_iris
train_versicolor$Species<-as.character(train_versicolor$Species)
train_versicolor$Species[train_versicolor$Species!="versicolor"]<-0
train_versicolor$Species[train_versicolor$Species=="versicolor"]<-1
train_versicolor$Species<-as.integer(train_versicolor$Species)
tune_versicolor<-tune.svm(Species~.,data=train_versicolor,gamma=10^(-6:-1),cost=10^(-1:1))
summary(tune_versicolor)
model_versicolor<-svm(Species~.,data=train_versicolor,kernel="radial",gamma=.1,cost=10,scale=TRUE,probabilities=TRUE,na.action=na.omit)
summary(model_versicolor)
predict_versicolor<-predict(model_versicolor,testset_iris[,-5])
tab_versicolor<-table(predict_versicolor,testset_iris[,5])
tab_versicolor

train_virginica<-trainset_iris
train_virginica$Species<-as.character(train_virginica$Species)
train_virginica$Species[train_virginica$Species!="virginica"]<-0
train_virginica$Species[train_virginica$Species=="virginica"]<-1
train_virginica$Species<-as.integer(train_virginica$Species)
tune_virginica<-tune.svm(Species~.,data=train_virginica,gamma=10^(-6:-1),cost=10^(-1:1))
summary(tune_virginica)
model_virginica<-svm(Species~.,data=train_virginica,kernel="radial",gamma=.1,cost=10,scale=TRUE,probabilities=TRUE,na.action=na.omit)
summary(model_virginica)
predict_virginica<-predict(model_virginica,testset_iris[,-5])
tab_virginica<-table(predict_virginica,testset_iris[,5])
tab_virginica

bind<-cbind(predict_setosa,predict_versicolor,predict_virginica)
classnames = c('setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica')
a<-apply(bind,1,classnames[which.max])
b<-cbind(bind,a)
table(b[,4],testset_iris$Species)
```

But, when I compared the confusion matrix of this result with confusion matrix of the result which used One vs One classifier (by default in radial kernel), One vs One gave better result. I believe that happened since there are only 3 classes in this case and One vs Rest works well when classes are large in number.